# uncheck a checkbox after closing the breadcrumb

Tags: html, jquery

I want to uncheck the ckeckbox when i click on the X to remove the breadcrumbs but it is not working. any help?

```
// HANDLE HIDE BREADCRUMB X BUTTON CLICK
$("#breadcrumbs").on("click", ".hidesegment", function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 var numbreadcrumbs = $("#breadcrumbs").find(".hidesegment").length;
if (numbreadcrumbs == 1) {
displayAllPersonas();
$("#filtercheckboxes").find("input:checked").prop("checked", false);
} else {
$("[segment='" + $(this).attr("segment") + "']").addClass("d-none");
updatePersonaCount();
}
```

HTML

```
<template id="breadcrumbtemplate">
<div id="crumbs">
    {{#each visibles}}
    <span class='p-2'>
        {{Segment}} ({{Count}})
        <img class='icon-mid toggle-icon hidesegment p-1' segment='{{Segment}}' data- 
        toggle='tooltip'
        data-placement='top' title='Click to hide' src='../img/icons/close.svg'>
    </span>
    {{/each}}
 </div>
 </template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Just replace #filtercheckboxes with #filterGroup and it worked.

$("#FilterGroup").find("input:checked").prop("checked", false);